# How to obtain a parameter 'total_words' for model.train() of gensim's doc2vec

Tags: python, gensim, doc2vec

As you might know, when you make a doc2vec model, you might do `model.build_vocab(corpus_file='...')` first, then do `model.train(corpus_file='...', total_examples=..., total_words=..., epochs=10)`.

I am making the model w/ huge wikipedia data file. So, I have to designate the 'total_examples' and the 'total_words' for parameters of train(). Gensim's [Tutorial](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_doc2vec_lee.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tutorials-run-doc2vec-lee-py) says that I can get the first one as `total_examples=model.corpus_count`. This is fine. But I don't know how to get second one, `total_words`. I can see the # of total words in the last log from model.build_vocab() as below. So, I directory put the number, like `total_words=1304592715`, but I'd like to designate it like model.corpus_count manner.
Can someone tell me how to obtain the number?
Thank you,

```
:
2022-01-29 15:03:22,377 : INFO : PROGRESS: at example #1290000, processed 1253078267 words (6147969/s), 7881288 word types, 0 tags
2022-01-29 15:03:26,434 : INFO : PROGRESS: at example #1300000, processed 1277357579 words (5984975/s), 7959581 word types, 0 tags
2022-01-29 15:03:30,955 : INFO : collected 8039609 word types and 1309452 unique tags from a corpus of 1309452 examples and 1304592715 words
:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to `model.corpus_count`, the tally of words from the last corpus provided to `.build_vocab()` should be cached in the model as `model.corpus_total_words`.